# How to use lambda expression on collections and arraylists

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have a private void code that compares two classes. In This typical code, i want to be able to use/apply lambda expression  where initially lambda is not used. Have tried several methods like maps , streams or filters but seems am not getting the exact format of the code,
   here is the code that i want to apply lambda expression . Only this code is needed

```java
     private void checkPrivileges(User user) {
            Collection<Role> roles = user.getAllRoles();
            List<String> requiredPrivs = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Role r : roles) {

                if (r.getRole().equals(RoleConstants.SUPERUSER)
                        && !Context.hasPrivilege(PrivilegeConstants.ASSIGN_SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_ROLE)) {
                    throw new APIException("User.you.must.have.role", new Object[] { RoleConstants.SUPERUSER });
                }
                if (r.getPrivileges() != null) {
                    for (Privilege p : r.getPrivileges()) {
                        if (!Context.hasPrivilege(p.getPrivilege())) {
                            requiredPrivs.add(p.getPrivilege());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (requiredPrivs.size() == 1) {
                throw new APIException("User.you.must.have.privilege", new Object[] { requiredPrivs.get(0) });
            } else if (requiredPrivs.size() > 1) {
                StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder("You must have the following privileges in order to assign them: ");
                for (String s : requiredPrivs) {
                    txt.append(s).append(", ");
                }
                throw new APIException(text.substring(0, text.length() - 2));
            }
        }
```

It has  corresponding class of Roles.java and Privilege.java.
 My issue is to only use lambda expression on only void class. Here is trial i did but it h=was half of my task

```java
role.getPrivileges().stream()
    .filter(()->{
          return Optional.of(privileges)
              .filter(given ->given.p.get privileges())
              .getOrElse("privilege required:" +p)});
```

Comment: Don't use lambda, instead try to improve your iterative code.

Comment: Since you're throwing a exceptions in the loop you cannot use `Streams` and its stages without any dirty hacks.

Comment: @Ravindra Ranwala any idea of how i can go with this

Answer (score 0):

I would flatten the for-if-for hierarchy and extract a constant + a checkmethod like:

```
private static final String ERROR_FORMAT = "You must have the following privileges in order to assign them: %s";

private void checkPrivileges(User user) {
    List<String> requiredPrivs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role r : user.getAllRoles()) {
        checkSuperUserPrivilege(r);
        Iterable<Privilege> privileges = r.getPrivileges() != null ? r.getPrivileges() : Collections.emptySet();
        for (Privilege p : privileges) {
            if (!Context.hasPrivilege(p.getPrivilege())) {
                requiredPrivs.add(p.getPrivilege());
            }
        }
    }
    if (requiredPrivs.size() == 1) {
        throw new APIException("User.you.must.have.privilege", new Object[] { requiredPrivs.get(0) });
    } else if (requiredPrivs.size() > 1) {
        throw new APIException(String.format(ERROR_FORMAT, String.join(", ", requiredPrivs)));
    }
}

private void checkSuperUserPrivilege(Role r) {
    if(r.getRole().equals(RoleConstants.SUPERUSER)
            && !Context.hasPrivilege(PrivilegeConstants.ASSIGN_SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_ROLE)) {
        throw new APIException("User.you.must.have.role", new Object[] { RoleConstants.SUPERUSER });
    }
}
```

As I stated in the comments it is a bad idea to handle this with Streams but here you go:

```
private static final String ERROR_FORMAT = "You must have the following privileges in order to assign them: %s";

private void checkPrivileges(User user) {
    List<String> requiredPrivs = user.getAllRoles().stream()
            .peek(this::checkSuperUserPrivilege)
            .map(Role::getPrivileges)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(Privilege::getPrivilege)
            .filter(p -> !Context.hasPrivilege(p))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (requiredPrivs.size() == 1) {
        throw new APIException("User.you.must.have.privilege", new Object[] { requiredPrivs.get(0) });
    } else if (requiredPrivs.size() > 1) {
        throw new APIException(String.format(ERROR_FORMAT, String.join(", ", requiredPrivs)));
    }
}

private void checkSuperUserPrivilege(Role r) {
    if(r.getRole().equals(RoleConstants.SUPERUSER)
            && !Context.hasPrivilege(PrivilegeConstants.ASSIGN_SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_ROLE)) {
        throw new APIException("User.you.must.have.role", new Object[] { RoleConstants.SUPERUSER });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks do much for your great idea, why would you say its a bda idea to flatter it in streams, thank alot

Comment: I think the declarative way is more bloated than the simple iterative style.

Comment: Actually it worked for me, though you termed it as a bad idea thanks

Comment: It's not about working, it's about readability and this is far better in the iterative style, though.